# Intermediate steps for solution of Wave ODE missing

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In *Operational Mathematics* (Churchill, 1971), the author states:

> The transform of $Y(x,t)$ therefore satisfies the conditions
>   $$s^2 y(x,s) = a^2 y_{xx}(x,s)$$
>   $$y(0,s) = 0, Ey_x(c,s)= f(s) $$ 
>   and the solution of this transformed problem is readily found to be:
>   $$y(x,s) = \frac{a}{E}f(s)\frac{\sinh(sx/a)}{s \cosh (sc/a)}$$

"Readily" is a very subjective term. To me it is really ambiguous how the author came up with the solution. This looks like a PDE with variable coefficients, but I am not sure what method to use.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047260/solution-of-1d-wave-equation-by-laplace-transform) thread is addressing a similar problem but the user does not get into how they solve the PDE (or is it an ODE in this case?)... Please provide the intermediate steps on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can check by differentiating that $a(s,x) = e^{sx/a}$ and $b(s,x) = e^{-sx/a}$ are two solutions of $s^2 y(x,s)=a^2 y_{xx}(x,s)$, e.g. $$a_x(s,x) = \frac{s}{a} e^{sx/a}, \:  a_{xx}(s,x) = \frac{s^2}{a^2} e^{sx/a} \Longrightarrow a^2 a_{xx}(s,x) = a^2 \left( \frac{s^2}{a^2} e^{sx/a}\right) = s^2 e^{sx/a} = s^2 a(s,x)$$
Because our equation is a linear 2nd-order ODE (in $x$), we know that its solutions can be written as combinations of our two linearly independent solutions $a(s,x)$ and $b(s,x)$, i.e. $$y(s,x) = k_1 e^{sx/a} + k_2 e^{-sx/a} $$

Because $y(0,s) = 0$, we see that $$0 = k_1 + k_2 \Longrightarrow k_2 = - k_1 \Longrightarrow y(s,x) = k_1 \left(e^{sx/a} - e^{-sx/a} \right) \Longrightarrow y(s,x) = 2 k_1 \sinh(sx/a)$$

We note $y_x = \frac{k_1s}{a} (e^{sx/a} + e^{-sx/a})$. Using the condition $E y_x(c,s) = f(s)$, we find that $$\frac{E k_1 s}{a} (e^{sc/a} + e^{-sc/a}) = f(s) \Longrightarrow k_1 = \frac{af(s)}{Es} \frac{1}{(e^{sc/a} + e^{-sc/a})} \Longrightarrow k_1 = \frac{a f(s)}{2Es \cosh(sc/a)}   $$

Plugging this into our expression for $y(s,x)$ in the line above gives $$y(s,x) = 2 \left(\frac{a f(s)}{2Es \cosh(sc/a)} \right) \sinh(sx/a) \Longrightarrow \boxed{y(s,x) = \frac{a f(s)}{Es} \frac{\sinh(sx/a)}{\cosh(sc/a)}} $$

Answer (score 0):

The equation has the form
$$
               \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}y(x,s) - \frac{s^2}{a^2} y(x,s) = 0.
$$
For a fixed $s$, that's really an ODE with solutions
$$
                 A\cosh(sx/a)+B\sinh(sx/a).
$$
The only difference is that the constants $A$ and $B$ will depend on $s$. The condition $y(0,s)=0$ forces $A=0$, which leaves
$$
                     y(x,s) = B(s)\sinh(sx/a).
$$
The condition $Ey_x(c,s)=f(s)$ translates to
$$
           EB(s)\cosh(sc)s/a=f(s),
$$
which gives $B(x)$ and, finally, $y=B(s)\sinh(sx/a)$ in the stated form.